# Reverse direction of swiping in viewpager for Arabic language

Tags: android

Yesterday, I posted a question about the PagerAdapter and how to achieve it when using database. I managed to sorted it out, however, I do not want the viewpager  to swipe/scroll left I want the opposite (swipe to right). The following is my code:

```
public class ScrollViewTest6 extends ActionBarAppActivity {

    private ViewPager awesomePager;
    private static int NUM_AWESOME_VIEWS;
    private Context cxt;
    private AwesomePagerAdapter awesomeAdapter;
    TextView tv;
    int _id;
    int row_numbers;
    int row_position;      
    private DataAdapter mySQLiteAdapter;
    private Cursor cursor;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    cxt = this;

    awesomeAdapter = new AwesomePagerAdapter(awesomeAdapter);
    awesomePager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.awesomepager);
    awesomePager.setAdapter(awesomeAdapter);

    mySQLiteAdapter = new DataAdapter(this);
    mySQLiteAdapter.createDatabase();
    mySQLiteAdapter.open();

   Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
   if (extras == null) {
       return;
   }

   _id = extras.getInt("id");
   row_numbers = extras.getInt("row_num");
   row_position = extras.getInt("row_pos");


   NUM_AWESOME_VIEWS = row_numbers;

   awesomePager.setCurrentItem(row_position);

   cursor = mySQLiteAdapter.get_AllColumns(); 
   this.startManagingCursor(cursor);


    this.awesomePager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
      }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels){
      }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position){
      }

    });
}

private class AwesomePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

    public AwesomePagerAdapter(PagerAdapter fm) {
       }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
      return NUM_AWESOME_VIEWS;
      }



    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {return POSITION_NONE;}
            @Override
            public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)cxt.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout, null);
                TextView Title = (TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.title);


                if (cursor != null ) {
                    if  (cursor.moveToPosition(position)) {                         
                        //do {
                            //cursor.moveToPosition(position);
                            String text = cursor.getString(
                                cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DataAdapter.KEY_Title));

                            Title.setText(text);    
                    }
                }                       

                ((ViewPager) collection).addView(layout,0);
                 return layout;
            }


            @Override
            public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view) {
                    ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((View) view);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
                    return view==((View)object);
            }

            @Override
            public void finishUpdate(View arg0) {
            }


            @Override
            public void restoreState(Parcelable arg0, ClassLoader arg1) {
            }

            @Override
            public Parcelable saveState() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void startUpdate(View arg0) {
            }

        }
}
```

I know some people suggest using 
setCurrentItem(int); //Last page

But that conflicts with the listview order.

e.g. Listview:

1

2

3

when we use the line above it shows  1 <- 2 <- 3 (starting from 3)

and I want 3 <- 2 <- 1 (starting from 1)

Comment: Why not simply reverse the list and then use `setCurrentItem(count - 1)`?

Comment: Fix code formatting please.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response guys...@AleksG I have tried setCurrentItem(count - 1) but it is not working. @BarneyHsiao does the code look better now?

Comment: @AleksG I get you now, "reverse the list": but how can I do that? is there an alternative method to do that such as overriding the swipe method?

Comment: I don't see any lists in the code your shown, so it's difficult to judge.  I'm guessing your page order is dictated by the order of rows read from sqlite database in the DataAdapter.  Just change the query to order the results in the opposite order.

Comment: Yes the list code is in the previous activity.. And to be honest I think that this is a very good idea i.e."reversing the order of the listview" even though it is not quite clear to me how! The problem in my case, the list shows book titles in the correct order, but would be possible to show the normal order book titles to user and then reverse it in the cursor before displaying it in the viewpager??

Comment: @AleksG You're the man I managed to reverse the cursor using "desc" and it worked... One minor thing is left now which is: since everything is reversed how can it know the exact position of the chosen screen from the list??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to AleksG

Here is what he suggested to do which works for the required purpose, so add the following line to the list:

```
setCurrentItem(count - 1)
```

Then in the cursor you'll need to set up the list order in the cursor `"_desc"`

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I face this issue and I resolve with this library
use it and your pagination will work right to left perfectly 
it work same as ViewPager

https://github.com/diego-gomez-olvera/RtlViewPager

```
 <com.booking.rtlviewpager.RtlViewPager
            android:id="@+id/arabicViewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

 arabicViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.arabicViewPager);
 adapterViewPager = new Adpt_fragmentPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
  arabicViewPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);

tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
 tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(arabicViewPager);
```